# Label of an entity not getting updated while importing an unmanaged solution in CRM 2016

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

I need help with updating the terminology used in one of my organizations. I have on-premises CRM, one dev organization and one test organization. I have created an unmanaged solution in dev organization and updated the entity messages, display names of some entities with the help of translations.

Now when I am importing this solution in the test organization, for some of the entities the display name is not getting updated. However, display name of fields of those entities are updated to newer terminology.

I have tried incrementing the version number of the solution & then importing the solution. However this does not resolve the issue. But, whenever a single entity is imported in an unmanaged solution from the dev org, the display name gets updated in the test org.

Comment: Did you include all entity forms into the solution? And did you use Publish all button after the import?

Comment: All forms are not included for the concerned entity. And yes, I did Publish all after the import. Shall I import all the forms?

Comment: One more thing, when I imported single entity in the unmanaged solution, I had not included any forms. Just required components were added in the solution.

Comment: I think it could help if you add the forms. You don't have to import them. Just add the forms into destination environment solution and the run Publish all again.

Comment: Including all forms did not help. However, we were able to resolve the issue by importing the entities along with metadata & all assets.